# Running out of Memory Training Google Big Bird with Huggingface

Tags: nlp, web-crawler, huggingface-transformers

I've been struggling to train Google's Big Bird model using the Huggingface transformers library due to out of memory errors. I have two Tesla V100 GPU's with 32 GB RAM each. I'm trying to train the google/bigbird-roberta-base model (https://huggingface.co/google/bigbird-roberta-base) on Spider (a natural language to SQL dataset) using the Huggingface trainer API. I'm using a batch size of 1 and the smallest version of this model, and still get OOM errors. According to the Big Bird paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14062), Big Bird can be trained on chips with 16 GB of memory, so I'm not sure why I'm running into OOM. Has anyone encountered trouble training Big Bird due to memory problems?

Here's the code that does the training:

```
rouge = datasets.load_metric("rouge")

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    predict_with_generate = True,
    evaluation_strategy = "steps",
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = batch_size,
    output_dir = "./",
    logging_steps = 2,
    save_steps = 400,
    eval_steps = 4
)

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels_ids = pred.label_ids
    pred_ids = pred.predictions

    pred_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    labels_ids[labels_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    label_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    rouge_output = rouge.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str, rouge_types=["rouge2"])["rouge2"].mid

    return {
        "rouge2_precision": round(rouge_output.precision, 4),
        "rouge2_recall": round(rouge_output.recall, 4),
        "rouge2_fmeasure": round(rouge_output.fmeasure, 4),
    }

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model = model,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    args = training_args,
    compute_metrics = compute_metrics,
    train_dataset = train_data,
    eval_dataset = val_data
)

trainer.train()
```

Here's the exact error I get:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 36.00 MiB (GPU 0; 31.75 GiB total capacity; 25.14 GiB already allocated; 21.50 MiB free; 26.23 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

Thanks so much for sharing any experience you have with this!

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue with a6000 which has 48gb ram and after setting batch size to 1 from 128 oom didn't occur I guess model is bigger than they said.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is the problem of huggingface. There is no OOM issue with the original code in https://github.com/google-research/bigbird.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).